# Problems with pushViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, push

i have an application where a there is a root view controller which pushes another a view controller into view. this view controller shows a table. when a cell is selected, it pushes to another view controller.
The first push works, but the second doesn't.
Here is my code for the selection of the cell in the table:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

TwoViewController *two = [[TwoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwoViewController": bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:two animated:YES];
[two release];
```

Any idea what i've done wrong? the codes I've used for both pushes are nearly identical...
I've tried this with putting this code in the touchUpInside event for a UIButton as well, but it does not work.
My guess is that there is no navigationController to push the view, but I don't know.
Please help!

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to push the first view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the *-initWithNibName:bundle* method on TwoViewController? My guess is it doesn't initialize correctly (i.e.: the method doesn't initialize the super class correctly).

**Edit:** I think I found the error, it's kind of obvious, actually.

Please check this code you posted:

```
initWithNibName:@"TwoViewController": bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

The error is near the `@"TwoViewController":` string, an extra semicolon that should not be there, change it to:

```
initWithNibName:@"TwoViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Log both 'two' and self.navigationController,

```
NSLog(@"two = %@", two);

NSLog(@"self.navigationController = %@", self.navigationController);
```

First you'll get to know, if one of them is nil (or both) and whether tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: gets called at all.

Comment: tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: gets called, I tried an NSLog(@"method is getting called") before the end of the method and got the message.

Comment: But, NSLog(@"self.navigationController = %@", self.navigationController); gives the result of 'null'. 

the two view controller gave this result. does this mean both are nil? how can i solve this?

two = <TwoViewController: 0x4e21f70>

Comment: Do you do any special initialization in `TwoViewController` or anything weird in `viewDidLoad`? `self.navigationController` should not be nil.

Answer (score 0):

Its navigation controller problem.Check it properly

Answer (score -1):

If the new view controller is part of a view, it probably doesn't have a navigation controller. Check if navigation controller is nil before pushing.

Comment: What you should do is provide the navigationController of the viewController that creates the view as a parameter to the view, so the view can make use of the navigationController of the parent viewController.

Comment: You should not have to do that. The `self.navigationController` property will be set automatically when you push the new view controller.

Comment: @kubi: His subview doesn't know of his navigationController, so he does have to provide the navigationController as a property (assign) or any other way to be able to push the viewController (or he has to call it on his 'superview' class, but that would be a less safe approach, can't always be sure the superview is a subclass of UIViewController).

Comment: He said that his class is a subclass of `UIViewController` that was pushed into the navigation stack. By default the navigationController property should be set, so he must be messing something up somewhere.

Comment: Ah yes, I guess I read it wrong, I thought I read he created a UIView subclass. In that case it's kind of puzzling why the navigationController is nil.